# Wrap text around <i> element

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am trying to wrap text around a  font-awesome element but I am getting the below
[image]

I want the text starts from the top and wrap around the  element. Is this possible?

Here is the code I wrote https://www.bootply.com/KtlIG2icyT

Comment: do you want icon next on title?

Comment: No, just the text around the icon. Thank you @UdhayTitus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this  `<i class="far fa-file fa-9x text-info" style="float: left; margin-right:7px;"></i>` instead of your `<i class="far fa-file fa-9x text-info pull-left"></i>`

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
    
<div class="card border-secondary my-3">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body text-secondary">
            <div class="card-text">
                <div class="row align-text-top">
                    <div class="col px-5 ">

                        <i class="far fa-file fa-9x text-info" style="float: left; margin-right:7px;"></i>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                    <div class="col">
                        <asp:fileupload id="fuDocument" runat="server" cssclass="btn btn-secondary" allowmultiple="False" height="200">
                        <p class="mt-2">
                            <asp:button id="btnUploadFile" runat="server" text="Υποβολή" cssclass="btn btn-primary" onclick="btnUploadFile_Click">
                        </asp:button></p>

                    </asp:fileupload></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


            <div id="push"></div>
```

Comment: Great! Ty both Udhay and @Tom Dickson your suggestion did the trick! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my work:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVNpQE

I was able to fix it by adding (see below) to your icon element:

```
float: left
```